# Opening of the second controller after a successful POST request

Tags: objective-c, macos, post, webview, afnetworking-2

I only learn Obj-c. I'm sending a login and password, get back to html page, how do I open the page after the request and closed loginWindowController? is the request itself :

```
    NSString *myLogin = usernameTextField.stringValue;
    NSString *myPassword = passwordTextField.stringValue;
    NSString *myFlash = flashpasswordTextField.stringValue;
    NSString *myNid = @"123456";
    NSString *urlString = @"http://neverlands.ru/game.php";
    NSString *ua = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36";

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer * requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [requestSerializer setValue:ua forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    AFHTTPResponseSerializer * responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"player_nick": myLogin, @"player_password": myPassword};
    [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //Условия после запроса 1
        if ([operation.responseString rangeOfString:@"NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - Второй пароль"].location == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Неверный логин или пароль");
        } else {
            NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"flcheck": myFlash, @"nid": myNid};
            [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                //Условия после запроса 2
                if ([operation.responseString rangeOfString:@"NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - бесплатная браузерная онлайн игра в стиле фэнтези"].location == NSNotFound) {
                    NSLog(@"Неверный флеш пароль");
                } else {
                    mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
                    [mainWindowController showWindow:self];
                    [mainWindowController addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                    NSLog(@"Авторизация произведена");
                }
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

what to write here that would have opened the current session?

```
  mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
                [mainWindowController showWindow:self];
                [mainWindowController addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:HERE]];
```

I tried `[mainWindowController addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];` But open page with a new session and writes that the username and password is not entered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making the same post request, with the same body, but looking for 2 different contents in the response?

You should just make 2 checks to the body of the response

```
NSString *importantStuff1 = @"NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - Второй пароль";
NSString *importantStuff2 = @"NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - бесплатная браузерная онлайн игра в стиле фэнтези";
if (([operation.responseString rangeOfString:importantStuff1].location == NSNotFound) &&
([operation.responseString rangeOfString:importantStuff2].location == NSNotFound))
{
  NSLog(@"Couldn't find the important stuff needed");
}
else
{
    mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
    [mainWindowController showWindow:self];
    [mainWindowController addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"Авторизация произведена");
}
```

pardon the variable names I have no idea what those words are haha

Comment: This site two-step authentication.
1. Login
2. If the username and password are correct then the page is loaded with flash elements to enter the second password http://neverlands.ru/swf/flashpass.swf

Then send two requests, and they are both successful, look at it through the Charles Web Proxy

It headers from the site after the first authorization <head>
<title>NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - Второй пароль</title>
</head> 
and and after the second <head>
<title>NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - бесплатная браузерная онлайн игра в стиле фэнтези</title>
</head>

Comment: right, sorry I didn't see where the parameters were reassigned here `NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"flcheck": myFlash, @"nid": myNid};`

So do you get an error with your current implementation?  Or does it just not show the window as you would expect when `showWindow` is called?

Comment: I need to be after the second request was successfully opened MainWindowController MainWindow.xib (It is a web browser that I made) and there the page load site after login.

Comment: Look after the second request charles web proxy in response I see:
   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="html">
    <head>
    <title>NeverLands: Земли, которых нет... - бесплатная браузерная онлайн игра в стиле фэнтези</title>
    <SCRIPT src="./js/game.js"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT>
        view_frames();
    </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    </html>`

Comment: How i understand need run this js for enter in site http://neverlands.ru/js/game.js